# Handle cart and order with REST API in Woocommerce

Tags: php, wordpress, api, woocommerce, woocommerce-rest-api

I just read about the Woocommerce REST API and it seems very promising.

But then I found out the API doesn't have any support to Sessions and Cart.

So if someone wants to write a SPA to communicate with the WC Backend, the developer should implement the session/cart/checkout methods by himself?

Answer (score 2):

There is no default api for the Cart or apply coupon. 
I created a custom endpoint for it.

Comment: @mr-ajay can you help me to implement the solution for cart api

Comment: Sure, Let me know how can I help you for the WooCommerce Cart REST API

Comment: @mr-ajay how did you implemented the cart API code. I am new to WooCommerce. can you please share the code, I have to create the same thing. thanks

Comment: Yes, I have implemented the cart REST API. sorry, I can't directly share my code for the API. You have to write your own code for that if you face any issue or problems then I can help you.